# How to manage kernel upgrades with ubuntu-zfs installed

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, zfs

I have ubuntu-zfs installed.  Periodically my system downloads minor kernel updates, but does not rebuild the ZFS module.  On the next reboot, none of the ZFS filesystems can be mounted.  In the past I've used `dpkg` to reconfigure the package and get it to rebuild the module.  Is there some automatic way this should be happening?  How do I configure it?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Perhaps you should reported it (at https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues according to the PPA page)? DKMS is supposed to rebuild the modules automatically on upgrade (and it doesn't need to be manually configured).

Comment: @muru Thanks!  Unfortunately I can't award the bounty to a comment.  Worth it, though.

Comment: that's fine. I doubt I'd ever have guessed what was going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Muru's tip about DKMS put me on the right track.  Seeing the `zfs-dkms` package I looked at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/zfs-dkms.list` which names `/usr/src/zfs-0.6.2/dkms.conf`.  I didn't have that file, nor any of `/usr/src/zfs-0.6.2`.

**Aha!**  I installed zfs to import an existing zpool and mount filesystems from a FreeBSD system, including a `/usr/src`.  So when I built this system I "lost" (covered up) everything that went into `/usr/src` as part of the initial configuration.  After that, any kernel upgrades will leave you with an updated grub that points at a kernel with no matching `zfs.ko`.  *Shouldn't that be an error?*  Previously when I fixed this it was on the system console after zfs failed to start -- so of course my original `/usr/src` was available to me.